# i3pystatus-python process blocks suspend and shutdown

Tags: arch-linux, process, i3

After using my arch-linux system a decent time, it can happen, that the i3pystatus process is not freezable anymore. As a result I can't suspend my laptop anymore. Killing the process (killall -9 python) doesn't have any effect: The process resides as a zombie. Even shutdown doesn't work anymore. It stops and waits for that process forever.

```
    -- The system has now entered the suspend sleep state.
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel: PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel: PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel: Freezing user space processes ... 
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel: Freezing of tasks failed after 20.004 seconds (2 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel: python          D ffff88027f215200     0   737    706 0x00000004
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  ffff880260a3b918 0000000000000086 ffffffff81812500 ffff880274480dc0
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  ffff880260a3b918 ffff880260a3c000 00000001003a4842 ffff880260a3b968
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  ffff88027f20e7c0 ffff88027528cb60 ffff880260a3b938 ffffffff8156dbfe
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel: Call Trace:
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff8156dbfe>] schedule+0x3e/0x90
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff81570533>] schedule_timeout+0x123/0x240
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff810dc4b0>] ? init_timer_key+0xb0/0xb0
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff8133cdc8>] ec_guard+0x159/0x1ab
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff810b4c60>] ? wake_atomic_t_function+0x60/0x60
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff8133db27>] acpi_ec_transaction+0x17a/0x353
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff8133dd5a>] acpi_ec_read+0x5a/0x7a
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff8133ddb9>] ec_read+0x3f/0x63
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffffa01f950f>] acpi_smbus_transaction+0x1bc/0x2c1 [sbshc]
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff810b4c60>] ? wake_atomic_t_function+0x60/0x60
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffffa01f962f>] acpi_smbus_read+0x1b/0x1d [sbshc]
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffffa0210108>] acpi_battery_get_state+0x71/0x90 [sbs]
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffffa02106ba>] acpi_sbs_battery_get_property+0x3d/0x440 [sbs]
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff8141ddf0>] power_supply_read_temp+0x40/0x80
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff814207b8>] thermal_zone_get_temp+0x58/0x70
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff81420a1d>] temp_show+0x2d/0x70
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff813cfb70>] dev_attr_show+0x20/0x50
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff812485d9>] sysfs_kf_seq_show+0xb9/0x130
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff81247060>] kernfs_seq_show+0x20/0x30
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff811f326c>] seq_read+0xec/0x390
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff81247ae7>] kernfs_fop_read+0x107/0x160
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff811d00f7>] __vfs_read+0x37/0x100
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff8126f8be>] ? security_file_permission+0xae/0xc0
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff811d09b7>] vfs_read+0x87/0x130
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff811d1755>] SyS_read+0x55/0xc0
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff8157162e>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x12/0x71
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel: python          D ffff88027f2d5200     0  5294    706 0x00000004
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  ffff8801adfb79c8 0000000000000086 ffff88027561b700 ffff8801e0a4ee00
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  0000000100000000 ffff8801adfb8000 ffff88007a76148c ffff8801e0a4ee00
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  00000000ffffffff ffff88007a761490 ffff8801adfb79e8 ffffffff8156dbfe
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel: Call Trace:
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff8156dbfe>] schedule+0x3e/0x90
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff8156dfe5>] schedule_preempt_disabled+0x15/0x20
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff8156f40a>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0xca/0x140
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff8156f49b>] mutex_lock+0x1b/0x30
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffffa01f93b9>] acpi_smbus_transaction+0x66/0x2c1 [sbshc]
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff81160d9c>] ? __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x17c/0x960
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff812bf647>] ? vsnprintf+0x267/0x530
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff812bd9ef>] ? string.isra.2+0x3f/0xd0
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffffa01f962f>] acpi_smbus_read+0x1b/0x1d [sbshc]
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffffa0210108>] acpi_battery_get_state+0x71/0x90 [sbs]
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffffa02106ba>] acpi_sbs_battery_get_property+0x3d/0x440 [sbs]
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff8141d7e9>] power_supply_get_property+0x19/0x30
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff8141e684>] power_supply_show_property+0x54/0x250
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff8141e984>] power_supply_uevent+0xc4/0x270
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff813d1a1b>] dev_uevent+0xbb/0x2b0
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff811b3826>] ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x1d6/0x200
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff813cf734>] uevent_show+0x94/0x100
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff813cfb70>] dev_attr_show+0x20/0x50
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff812485d9>] sysfs_kf_seq_show+0xb9/0x130
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff81247060>] kernfs_seq_show+0x20/0x30
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff811f326c>] seq_read+0xec/0x390
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff81247ae7>] kernfs_fop_read+0x107/0x160
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff811d00f7>] __vfs_read+0x37/0x100
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff8126f8be>] ? security_file_permission+0xae/0xc0
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff811d09b7>] vfs_read+0x87/0x130
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff811d1755>] SyS_read+0x55/0xc0
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:  [<ffffffff8157162e>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x12/0x71
    Nov 10 16:26:22 mobook kernel:
```

The same thing happened to me when I used i3status instead of py3status (I changed to py3status to overcome this issue). 
Any ideas what's the problem and how to track the bug?

Best